# Zend From Decorators not working with ZendX_JQuery_Form

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using two decorator
 - To get tabular form alignment
 - To get date picker (ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker)

both are working individually, but not at a same time

Error:

```
Warning: Exception caught by form: Cannot render jQuery form element without at least one decorator implementing the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElementMarker' interface. Default decorator for this marker interface is the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElement'. Hint: The ViewHelper decorator does not render jQuery elements correctly.
```

My Get Form Function:

```
$form = new Form_Job();
$form->setDecorators(Decorator::$formDecorators);
$form->setElementDecorators(Decorator::$elementDecorators);
$form->getElement('submit')->setDecorators(Decorator::$buttonDecorators);
```

Form class Form_Job()

```
class Form_Job extends ZendX_JQuery_Form {
   public function init() {
        $element = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('date_from');
        $element->setLabel('Campaign Period From :');
        $element->setRequired(true);
        $element->setAttrib('size', '10');
        $element->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');

        $this->addElement($element);
   }
}
```

I got this help from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html

> jQuery Decorators: Beware the Marker
>   Interface for UiWidgetElements
>
> By default all the jQuery Form
>   elements use the
>   ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElement decorator for rendering the jQuery
>   element with its specific view helper.
>   This decorator is inheritly different
>   from the ViewHelper decorator that is
>   used for most of the default form
>   elements in Zend_Form. To ensure that
>   rendering works correctly for jQuery
>   form elements at least one decorator
>   has to implement the
>   ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElementMarker
>   interface, which the default decorator
>   does. If no marker interface is found
>   an exception is thrown. Use the marker
>   interface if you want to implement
>   your own decorator for the jQuery form
>   element specific rendering.

But i need code to implement this, please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer:-

I used

```
public static $formJQueryElements = array(
        array('UiWidgetElement', array('tag' => '')), // it necessary to include for jquery elements
        array('Errors'),
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'span')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td', 'class' =>'element')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
);
$form->getElement('jq_date')->setDecorators(Decorator::$formJQueryElements);
```

this works well for tabular alignment, for jquery elements !!!!!